# Pandas convert string to end of month date

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have this problem where 1 of the columns in my df is entered in as string, but I want to convert it into end of date month in python.  For example,

```
   Id Name    Date  Number
0   1    A  201601       5
1   2    B  201602       6
2   3    C  201603       4
```

The Date column has the year and month as string.  Ideally, my goal is:

```
   Id Name        Date  Number
0   1    A  01/31/2016       5
1   2    B  02/29/2016       6
2   3    C  03/31/2016       4
```

I was able to do this on excel using Endmonth and cut string, but when I tried pd.to_datetime in python, it didn't work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

we can using `MonthEnd`

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd
df.Date=(pd.to_datetime(df.Date,format='%Y%m')+MonthEnd(1)).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
df
Out[1336]: 
   Id Name        Date  Number
0   1    A  01/31/2016       5
1   2    B  02/29/2016       6
2   3    C  03/31/2016       4
```

Comment: Nice solution ! :-)

Comment: @Wen I got this error when I run the code:
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType' 
and the output is NaT
Is it because my input is still string?

Comment: @TylerNG  `df.Date=(pd.to_datetime(df.Date.astype(str),format='%Y%m')+MonthEnd(1)).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')`

Comment: @TylerNG the error come from the int , your `df.Date.dtype` should be int, after convert to str as above , you should be fine

Comment: @TylerNG yw happy coding

Answer (score 2):

you can use [PeriodIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.PeriodIndex.html):

```
In [36]: df['Date'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df['Date'].astype(str), freq='M').strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

In [37]: df
Out[37]:
   Id Name        Date  Number
0   1    A  01/31/2016       5
1   2    B  02/29/2016       6
2   3    C  03/31/2016       4
```